# Can CMD be aided, directly and/or by aiding AC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, combat-maneuver

**Can one Aid another's CMD?**

Let's look at two possible ways, and then a twist.

**1. Can one aid CMD directly?**

Aid Another lists several uses, of which CMD isn't one of them:

> If you succeed, your friend gains either a +2 bonus on his next attack roll against that opponent or a +2 bonus to AC against that opponent’s next attack...You can also use this standard action to help a friend in other ways, such as when he is affected by a spell, or to assist another character’s skill check.

Based on this, I'm inclined to think that CMD isn't something one can aid directly (though *"You can also use this standard action to help a friend in other ways"* leaves a lot of wiggle room, and I wonder if I'm something defined elsewhere as well.)

**2. What about aiding AC, since many bonuses to AC automatically boost CMD as well?**

CMD says:

> CMD = 10 + Base attack bonus + Strength modifier + Dexterity modifier + special size modifier + miscellaneous modifiers

And then Miscellaneous Modifiers clarifies:

> A creature can also add any circumstance, deflection, dodge, insight, luck, morale, profane, and sacred bonuses to AC to its CMD. Any penalties to a creature’s AC also apply to its CMD

Untyped bonuses (like that from Aid) aren't listed, so perhaps aiding AC *doesn't* boost CMD. Do I have that right, or am I missing something?

**3. If one can aid CMD, does it matter if one is aiding their CMD vs an attack (e.g. someone's trying to grapple them) vs aiding the controller of a grapple's CMD, to help them resist a grappled foe escaping?**

I ask because the latter attempt to escape a grapple *isn't* an attack:

> If you are grappled, you can attempt to break the grapple as a standard action by making a combat maneuver check (DC equal to your opponent’s CMD; this does not provoke an attack of opportunity)

Comment: "How do aid and CMD interact?" seems like a well-enough focused question. Voted to leave open..